# Finding Optimal Value of K

Tags: python, numpy, k-means

How to calculate mean_distances from centroid to each point in the cluster for k clusters.

**Formula:**

[image]

**My Code:**

```
def mean_distances(k, X):
"""
Arguments:

k -- int, number of clusters
X -- np.array, matrix of input features

Returns:

Array of shape (k, ), containing mean of sum distances 
    from centroid to each point in the cluster for k clusters
"""

### START CODE HERE ###
mod = KMeans(X, k)
clusters, final_centrs = mod.final_centroids()
dist = []
for i in range(k):
    d =  np.sum(np.linalg.norm((clusters[i] - final_centrs[i, :])**2)).mean()
    dist.append(d)
return dist
### END CODE HERE ###
```

But it doesn't work correctly.
*(P.S. without scklearn, just numpy)*

Comment: Where does KMeans() come from? Also: indenting issues.

Answer (score 0):

You are taking the mean of each element of the outer sum (i.e. each internal sum), as opposed to the mean of the outer sum:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

def mean_distances(k, X):
    """
    Arguments:

        k -- int, number of clusters
        X -- np.array, matrix of input features

    Returns:

        Array of shape (k, ), containing mean of sum distances 
        from centroid to each point in the cluster for k clusters
    """

    mod = KMeans(X, k)
    clusters, final_centrs = mod.final_centroids()
    dist = []
    for i in range(k):
        d =  np.sum(np.linalg.norm((clusters[i] - final_centrs[i, :])**2))
        dist.append(d)
    return dist.mean()
```